# Grub rescue after deleting Ubuntu partition

Tags: grub2, partitioning, uninstall, grubrescue

Today I have a big problem; long story short, I installed Ubuntu in dual boot a long tine ago and I wanted to delete Ubuntu and I did so but incorectly, I might think, by reformating the partitions that were allocated to Ubuntu in Disk Management software provided by Windows (I deleted everything that was not related to NTFSC). However, I left this partition empty without expanding the Windows partition because I wasn't able to. Because I didnt know what ai was doing because I followed a random tutorial on the internet, I restarted my computer and I got :
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
I already tried to get rid of it by tring alot of techniques on internet like using liveUSB ubuntu console or windows repair cmd or directly in grub prompt.

I wonder if I can get rid of it and CONSERVE my windows 10 version with all my files.

Thanks in advance for your help and I hope somebody is going to response because I am very tired of this problem

Thank you,
Dominic

Comment: If a Windows user best way is to use your Windows 10 repair/recovery disk. If system is UEFI, use UEFI boot menu. If system is BIOS install Windows boot loader to MBR. How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7/8/10 BIOS bootloader 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader  If UEFI:http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Boot the Ubuntu Live CD/USB.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/ms-sys/files/ms-sys%20stable/2.4.1/ms-sys-2.4.1.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ms-sys*.tgz
cd ms-sys
make
make install
ms-sys --ntfs /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu partition must have been hosting grub. But this is what you can do:

1. Insert live Ubuntu installation disk
2. Run in terminal:

```
sudo -i
add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt update
sudo apt install boot-repair
boot-repair
```

3. chose "recommended repair"
4. Boot-repair will ask you to paste text in the terminal twice. Open new terminal window to do so.
5. Restart when finished, removing Ubuntu installation disk.